# Asking credential popup on sharepoint 2013 public facing site

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jquery-ajax

I have sharepoint 2013 site as public facing migrated from 2010. I have one page where I am getting items from the list using rest api. when i access this page without login as an anonymous user it asking me credential popup.

Seems like it is CORS issue. any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: got the solution. need to uncheck the "Require Use of remote interface permission" checkbox in site permission for specifc list of library on which you want access

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable anonymous access for the list? To access the page anonymously, you need to make sure the list also could be accessed for anonymous users.

Comment: I have given the anonymous user read permission but it also not able to access the list

Comment: Sorry , I am able to access the list but not able to access it using jquery ajax rest api

Comment: Did you disable " Limited Access user permission lockdown mode" feature at site collection level? If not, please disable it,then test again. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31721.enabling-anonymous-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-calls.aspx

Comment: Yes , tried after disbaling it. still having the same problem

Comment: got the solution. added in comment to question

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a CORS problem.  There is a thread that has some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367758/enable-cors-in-sharepoint-2013